# Is it possible to define virtual fields (SQL function calls) in entities?

Tags: mysql, cakephp, orm, cakephp-3.0, sql-function

Is their way, we can add MySQL custom function in Entity

```
protected $_virtual = ['check_tenant' => '(check_tenant(Tenants.id))'];
```

I would like to call following query in with `find()` method

```
//SELECT id, first_name, check_tenant(Tenants.id) FROM tenants AS Tenants

$this->Tenants->find()->all();
```

If I can define custom MySQL function in the virtual field then it would automatically return in the result set

I am able to pass the new field in `select()` method

```
$this->Tenants->find()
->select(['id', 'check_tenant' => '(check_tenant(Tenants.id))'])->all();
```

But i would like to define globally, so the new field don't need to pass in every `find` call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtual *properties* in CakePHP 3.x are not the same as virtual *fields* in CakePHP 2.x, the latter were used in SQL queries, and the former are being used on PHP level, usually with data already present in the entity.

If you want your custom field to be present in *all* queries, then you could for example use the `Model.beforeFind()` event to modify the queries accordingly:

```php
// in TenantsTable class

public function beforeFind(\Cake\Event\Event $event, \Cake\ORM\Query $query, array $options)
{
    return $query
        // select custom fields (functions builder usage not required, but advised)
        ->select(function (\Cake\ORM\Query $query) {
            return ['check_tenant' => $query->func()->check_tenant([
                'Tenants.id' => 'identifier'
            ])];
        })
        // ensure that the tables default fields are being selected too
        ->enableAutoFields(true); // autoFields() before CakePHP 3.4
}
```

Another less invasive option would be custom finders, that you explicitly use where you need them:

```php
// in TenantsTable class

public function findWithTenantCheck(\Cake\ORM\Query $query, array $options)
{
    return $query
        ->select(/* ... */)
        ->enableAutoFields(true);
}
```

```php
// query data

$query = $this->Tenants->find('withTenantCheck');
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Table Objects > Lifecycle Callbacks > beforeFind](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#beforefind)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Entities > Creating Virtual Properties](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#creating-virtual-properties)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Retrieving Data & Results Sets > Using Finders to Load Data](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#using-finders-to-load-data)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Retrieving Data & Results Sets > Custom Finder Methods](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#custom-finder-methods)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Using SQL Functions](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-sql-functions)**

Comment: The event is worked well, it's working globally even with pagination thank you, I need to modify `['check_tenant' => $query->func()->check_tenant(['Tenants.id' => 'identifier'])]` to `['check_tenant' => 'check_tenant(Tenants.id)']` becuase it's passing as string not a sql field (Tenants.id), not sure, may be it's related to my cakephp older `3.0.6` version.

Comment: @Girish That could very well be the case, an upgrade might be advised, `3.0.6` isn't even the latest `3.0` branch release (which doesn't receive any updates anymore), and it's more than 3 years old already.